# How to Debug MAUI App that does not start

Tags: windows-10, maui

I have a self-contained MAUI App compiled for Windows. On some systems it works as expected on some others it won't start. You start the app from the start menu but it appears as nothing would happen. No window poping up, no error message, ...

In the Windows Event log there is an Application Error for the .exe of the App:

```
Name of the faulty application: MyApp.exe, Version: 1.0.0.0, Timestamp: 0x64b07659
Name of the faulty module: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll, Version: 3.0.0.2212, Timestamp: 0x7dc2efab
Errorcode: 0xc000027b
Error Offset: 0x00000000007cd8ec
```

I already googled for the error code and faulty module, but it seems to be a non-specific problem. I also tried to start the app from command line and run it as admin, same problem. Is there a way to get a more precise error message, why the app isn't starting?

Comment: It seems the offending computers have missing dependencies. As a first attempt, I would compare the installed programs (Apps & Features on Windows 10) of two (running and crashing) machines. Probably there are missing components (.NET SDK, C++ redistributables, runtimes etc.) on the crahing machines.

Comment: "a self-contained MAUI App compiled for Windows"* - Is this a **packaged** app, or did you copy files to the other computers?

Comment: It is **packaged**. It installs normally even on the machines, where it won't start

Comment: Did you try to copy the project to the device whose system can't start the app to debug?

Comment: Running the app as an admin "solved" the problem for me.